# how to post a value to a php page in a facebook app?

Tags: html, facebook

I am a noob facebook app developer and I would be very grateful for a little hand-holding getting started by professionals. I created a very simple app. It's only one file (index.php) and it has an html form that posts a value back to index.php to display. It worked before I added a "share to wall" request to the authentication. Now (I guess) there is a redirection before realoading the index.php, so it gets no $_POST value and it doesn't display the entered value. I would be very grateful if somebody would actually check out my app and its code and tell me how to fix it. (I think it's important to mention that it requests permission to post to the user's wall, but actually it doesn't post anything to the wall. I want to add that functionality later.) Here is the app:
 https://apps.facebook.com/webszebb/
 And here is the code (screenshot):
 http://webszebb.hu/indexphp.png
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity I'd suggest doing something like:

```
<html header stuff>
<?php
...snip...
if ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'whatever the action is, i.e: action="?foo" would be foo here') {
  print('Your previous number was ' . $_POST['my_number']);
} else {
  print('form');
}
?>
```

But to answer your question I'm assuming the $fb->api('/me') probably redirects you.